# I am getting the message 'The type EventFiringWebDriver is deprecated' in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I understand that in Selenium 4 that 'EventFiringWebDriver' has been depreciated. What is the alternative? What changes do I need to make in my code? Please see the screenshot attached of the code. Also pasting the code below:

```
package testcases;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import listener.DriverUpdate;

public class TC_001 {
    
    @Test
    public void tc001()
    {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        //Step 2
        EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        
        //Step 3
        DriverUpdate listener = new DriverUpdate();
        eventDriver.register(listener);
        
        
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.theTestingWorld.com");
        
        
    }

}
```

I am expecting to be able to create the object of EventFiringWebDriver and then later I want to be able to register my class (Where we are inheriting EventDriver interface) with the EventDriver. But of course it won't allow me to do this, since it is depreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In Selenium 4, I am using 4.8.3 below is how you do it

First create a Listener Class which implements WebDriverListener interface
Now we will override some of its methods like below, you can override more as per your requirement

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverListener;

public class Listener implements WebDriverListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeAnyWebDriverCall(WebDriver driver, Method method, Object[] args) {
        System.out.println("beforeAnyWebDriverCall");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterGet(WebDriver driver, String url) {
        System.out.println("after get");
    }
}
```

Now in the class where you create you Webdriver you need to use EventFiringDecorator class to register your Listeners and Decorate the driver

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringDecorator;

public class EventTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver");
        WebDriver original = new ChromeDriver();
        Listener listener = new Listener();//Create instance of Listener Class
        EventFiringDecorator<WebDriver> decorator = new EventFiringDecorator<>(listener); //Pass listener to constructor
         
        WebDriver decorated = decorator.decorate(original);
        decorated.get("http://www.theTestingWorld.com");
        decorated.quit();
    }
}
```

Now when this code runs , you will get below output,

```
beforeAnyWebDriverCall // printed before getURL
after get // After getURL
beforeAnyWebDriverCall // printed before Quit
```

you can check this good example given here in Selenium docs
[EventFiringDecorator](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringDecorator.html)

Methods Related to Navigation which you can override

```
 // Navigation

  default void beforeAnyNavigationCall(WebDriver.Navigation navigation, Method method, Object[] args)  {}
  default void afterAnyNavigationCall(WebDriver.Navigation navigation, Method method, Object[] args, Object result)  {}

  default void beforeTo(WebDriver.Navigation navigation, String url) {}
  default void afterTo(WebDriver.Navigation navigation, String url) {}

  default void beforeTo(WebDriver.Navigation navigation, URL url) {}
  default void afterTo(WebDriver.Navigation navigation, URL url) {}

  default void beforeBack(WebDriver.Navigation navigation) {}
  default void afterBack(WebDriver.Navigation navigation) {}

  default void beforeForward(WebDriver.Navigation navigation) {}
  default void afterForward(WebDriver.Navigation navigation) {}

  default void beforeRefresh(WebDriver.Navigation navigation) {}
  default void afterRefresh(WebDriver.Navigation navigation) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This really helped. So I have the class sorted, where I have created the WebDriver. However in the Listener class I seem to be getting the following error: The method afterNavigateTo(String, WebDriver) of type DriverUpdate must override or implement a supertype method. See screenshot in my separate comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply! This really helped. So I have the class sorted, where I have created the WebDriver.

However, in the Listener Class I seem to be getting the following:

[image: Error in Listener class]

> The method afterNavigateTo(String, WebDriver) of type DriverUpdate must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: there is no afterNavigateTo method in WebDriverListener interface which you are trying to override thats why you are getting the error,If you click on WebDriverListener interface you can see the list of methods that you can override
For you Navigation related use cases I have updated above to list down the methods you can override related to navigation

Comment: You can also view the list by doing right click then Click Source then Click Override/implements Methods options, it will show you the list of methods which you can override, you can select any methods from there

Comment: Ah my mistake, actually afterNavigateTo method is taken from WebDriverEventListener interface which has been deprecated. I wanted an alternative or the equivalent of that method in WebDriverListener interface

Comment: Alternative now would be to override
beforeTo(WebDriver.Navigation navigation, String url)
afterTo(WebDriver.Navigation navigation, String url)

Comment: Thank you. Also, what would be the equivalent of beforeFindBy (Taken from WebDriverEventListener interface) method in WebDriverListener interface ?

Comment: it would be `public void beforeFindElement(WebDriver driver, By locator)`